# command errors in a file but runs fine on a shell

Tags: ruby, shell, unix, ssh, environment-variables

I am trying to run a command in a script, something like this one:

```
ssh user@host:/bin/echo > /home/path/file.log
```

Now when I run this command on a command line it works fine, however when put in a script (shell or ruby ) it cribs saying:
/bin/sh: /home/path/*.log: No such file or directory

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Update:

It's weird that same thing is not being executed now even on the shell when I use putty. I have verified that the path and file exists on remote machine which is being ssh'ed into.

Comment: What specific file do you want to redirect into?

Comment: these are some log files that I want to set to blank before proceeding .. I cannot delete them since the application is continuously writing to them ..

Comment: I edited the question to change `sh` to `ssh` as that is apparently what you are trying to say.  With that, the situation is more complex; the `ssh` command is a syntax error, so it cannot have worked.  Basically, you are trying to run `echo` on the remote host, but redirect its output to a local file.  If you want to touch remote files, you need to run the redirection remotely.  I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the files. If it works from the command line then your interactive shell is not a standard shell.

```
for f in /home/path/*.log; do
     :>"$f"
done
```

Note also the use of a null command; in many shells, you don't need a command at all. Your `echo` puts an unattractive empty line at the beginning of each file.

If you are attempting to run this remotely, you will need to quote it:

```
ssh user@remote 'for f in /home/path/*.log; do :>"$f"; done'
```

Comment: thnx tripleee . Its the same without a regular expression. I updated the question.

Comment: There is no regular expression anywhere.  Do you mean without the wildcard?  I have an explanation for that.  If the wildcard would previously match exactly one file, then there would not be an ambiguous redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine when I put quotes:
ssh user@host:"/bin/echo > /home/path/file.log"